# Android Studio Behind Window Touches

Tags: android

**FIXED**
I apologize that I found my answer as quickly as I did and may have wasted some of yall's time. I changed the flag to `TYPE_WALLPAPER`. This allows me to press the game's fire icon. Thank you guys anyways. Have a great day!

So basically what I am doing is drawing a floating ui over a game on android.

What the floating UI is doing is adding custom colors to the  main game UI to give it  more of a custom feel.

For example, I draw a new fire icon over the game's fire icon to give a cooler affect.

The problem I face is :
- I cannot touch the game's fire icon, only mine.
- I have tried setting the overlay type to `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` and `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL`, and it just stops the game from running.

Code example :

`final WindowManager.LayoutParams fireIconOverlay = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, overlay, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);`

Would you have any suggestions?

My custom UI is embedded in the game's code.
It is not an external app.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow. Would you be able to provide a MCVE please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added. The code snippet is what needs to modified. As you can see, I have tried adding `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`, hoping that if I press the area where my fire icon is, it would allow me to press the game's fire icon as well. Unfortunately, this is not the case.

Comment: Solution found. `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` was replaced with `TYPE_WALLPAPER` and it now allows me to touch the game fire icon behind my icon.

Comment: Just answer your own question (click answer your own question when looking at your own question) if you fixed it this could be useful to someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` to `TYPE_WALLPAPER` allows me to press the game fire icon behind my custom fire icon. I cannot go into full depth on why this works, just did some research here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams